# Where can I ask questions about the Kronos InTouch?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the [Kronos InTouch](https://www.kronos.com/resources/intouch-brochure). Specifically, how many registered employees it can hold before reaching maximum capacity.

(For reference, the Kronos InTouch is a self-service badge reader used by businesses for workforce management and recording employee timestamps)

Would my question be best for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/), or some other site?

<sub>*Note: Stack Overflow has a tag for [Kronos Workforce Central](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kronos-wfc/info), but that is only applicable for programming-related questions.*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kronos has an online community for questions like this, where you might be able to get a quicker, more direct answer. The URL is https://community.kronos.com. Hope that helps!

Comment: Account registration on the Kronos forums requires a company-specific Solution ID. In my case, I was able to retrieve one by contacting my company's Kronos IT support team.